# Use \usetikzlibrary{quotes} with \MakeOuterQuote{"} from csquots

Tags: tikz-pgf, csquotes, tikzlibrary

Is there a way to use (disable) `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` in tikz while using `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"} %breaks tikz library

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\tikz \node ["abc" draw] {node};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\tikzset{every picture/.prefix code=\DisableQuotes}
```

or

```
\tikzset{every picture/.prefix style={execute at begin picture=\DisableQuotes}}
```

after loading TikZ.
The first one is executed a little bit earlier then the second when a TikZ picture is started.

The macro `\DeleteQuotes` can also be used.

Comment: instead of `append`ing `prefix`ing is a bit safer.